# Can we find out if we are uniformly accelerating through flat spacetime by looking at non-accelerating clocks?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, tidal-effect

The equivalence principle states that locally you can't tell if you are accelerating through flat spacetime or are at rest in a uniform gravitational field.

Does this mean you can only tell the difference by looking at "free", non-accelerated clocks which are spatially separated in the direction of motion? In a uniform field there is no tidal effect affecting the spatial distances. So is it only by looking at free clocks we can answer the question?

I wiil clarify. Assume you are accelerating uniformly in flat spacetime. In this spacetime we place clocks at fixed distances wrt an observer at rest, in the direction of your accelerated motion. The clocks are all synchronized in the frame of this observer at rest. The observer at rest then takes two clocks and brings them to you in your accelerating ship.

The we have a situation where you are at rest in a uniform gravity field. Say at a fixed height above an infinite massive plate. There is an observer falling freely in this field and there are clocks in his frame, separated at equal distances in the direction of the velocity you seem to have for him. The clocks were synchronized too. When? I don't know. And again the observer takes two clocks, the same distance apart as in the previous example, and brings them to your rocket. And again you compare them.

My question is whether there is a difference in both clock comparisons.

Comment: What do you mean by non-accelerated clocks? In GR all motion solely under gravity is non-accelerated.

Comment: @user7896 I mean clocks that fall freely in a gravity field or are non-accelerated in flat spacetime.

Comment: First of all if in GR the equivalence principle holds so there is no way to distinguish uniform acceleration from uniform gravity. Secondly, for the observer to get the clock in your frame would involve acceleration in both cases. The readings on the clock would depend on the the details of the process.